# Change color from one value to another based on offset

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to change 1 color value which will be represented by offset 1.0 to another color value represented by offset 0.0.

I don't want to use `ValueAnimator` because animation will be made by myself (function to change color is called everytime offset changes based on scroll listener) and I don't need to really "animate" it by duration.

I tried this:

```
val color = ArgbEvaluator().evaluate(offset, R.color.start, R.color.end)
```

But color is type of `Any` and not color I can set as `backgroundTint` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, you're just missing a cast.

```
val color = ArgbEvaluator().evaluate(offset, startColor, endColor) as Int

myView.setBackgroundColor(color)
```

Comment: Tried this but ArgbEvaluator is not making great result at all. That was just example. It is switching between 2 color values but they are weird. It should go from blue to white but its flickering with hues of red/pink. So this is clearly not great tool to do that.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a snippet of where you're trying to transition the color from blue to white.

Answer (score 0):

[ArgbEvaluator#evaluate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ArgbEvaluator#evaluate(float,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) takes an

> Object: A 32-bit int value representing colors in the separate bytes of the parameter

as its second and third arguments. What you are using are the resource id of the colors you want. You will need to translate those resource ids into 32-bit colors.

```
val startColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.start, null)
val endColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.end, null)
val color = ArgbEvaluator().evaluate(offset, startColor, endColor)
binding.textView.setBackgroundColor(color as Int)
```